# HQL : The column must appear in GROUP BY or in Select

Tags: java, hibernate, hql

I've this query with WrappedBean :

```
buffer.append("SELECT new myPackage.WrappedBean(E.debitant.id,  E.dateCalcul, E.verse, E.incidenceReprise, E.soldeSoumission) ");
buffer.append("FROM " + getEntityClassName() + " E ");
buffer.append("LEFT JOIN E.debitant DT ");
buffer.append("WHERE E.debitant.id = :idDebitant ");
buffer.append("AND YEAR(E.dateCalcul) = :year ");
buffer.append("GROUP BY E.debitant.id");

hqlQuery = session.createQuery(buffer.toString());
hqlQuery.setInteger("idDebitant", idDebitant);
hqlQuery.setInteger("year", year);
```

I've created WrappedBean for returning somme columns and for using Group BY.

When i try to execute it, i obtain this error :

**org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERREUR: The column « complement0_.date_calcul » must appear in GROUP BY clause or must be used in Select** (i translate the error from french)

My POSTGRES query doesnt contain date_calcul in Group BY.

Another problem, in my query i've also this :

```
SUM(CASE WHEN YEAR(dateCalcul)=@PECAnnee AND verse>0 THEN verse ELSE 0 END)
```

I know in HQL, we cant do case when in select, for this reason, i dont add SUM to column verse

What i've forgot ?

Answer (score 2):

> My POSTGRES query doesnt contain date_calcul in Group BY

That's the problem and what Postgres is complaining about. Why isn't it in the SQL query? Because it isn't in the HQL query. Any column that is selected without the use of some aggregate method like sum(), min(), max() etc. needs to be part of the GROUP BY clause since otherwise the DB doesn't know how to handle multiple values/conflicts.

As an example, what value of `E.dateCalcul` should be passed to `WrappedBean` if there are multiple debitors (debitants) (which is most probably the case since otherwise there wouldn't be any need for the GROUP BY clause)?

So to fix this either use

```
GROUP BY E.debitant.id,  E.dateCalcul, E.verse, E.incidenceReprise, E.soldeSoumission
```

or use aggregate functions, e.g.

```
WrappedBean(E.debitant.id,  max(E.dateCalcul), min(E.verse), max(E.incidenceReprise), sum(E.soldeSoumission))
```

Comment: Here is my Query in PostGres :

`SELECT  id_debitant, dateCalcul, verse, soldeSoumission
FROM calc_cdr
WHERE   id_debitant = someValue
        AND YEAR(dateCalcul)  =   @PECAnnee
GROUP BY id_debitant`

Comment: @Pasja95 well, Postgres should complain about that query as well. Also the query contains `dateCalcul` but not `date_calcul`. If the former is the correct name then have a look at your mapping since that's most probably wrong.